# Fractional part of a widely spread unimodal random variable is uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've found following exercise in a textbook:

Let $X$ be a random variable with density $f(a)da$ and $Y:=X - \lfloor X \rfloor$ its fractional part.

I've already shown that $Y$ has the density $g(b) db$ with $g(b) := \sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty} f(b + n)$.

The next task is to show that $\left| g(b) - 1 \right| \leq \sup_a f(a)$ if $f$ is unimodal. Whereby – in this book – a function is called unimodal if it first rises monotonously and then falls monotonously.

There is a hint that I do not know how to use: Make an estimate about $g(b) - g(b')$ for $0 \leq b \lt b' \lt 1$.

The last step is straightforward if this result is proved. Since the fractional part has to be between zero and one, the inclusion $\operatorname{supp}(g) \subset [0, 1)$ is true. If $\sup f \ll 1$ holds, then $g(b) \approx 1$ for $b\in[0, 1)$. So $g$ is *more or less* uniformly distributed.

Comment: Where are you stuck? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I don't even know where to start. Based on the clue, I would like to apply the triangle inequality. So that I get $|g(b) - 1| \leq |g(b) - g(b')| + |g(b') - 1|$. But that won't get me anywhere.

If I start with the hint, I won't get anywhere either. I get $g(b) - g(b') = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(b + n) - \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(b' + n) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(b+n) - f(b' - n)$. I think this is allowed, since the series converge absolutely. I suspect that this is where unimodality comes into play? Both equations let me think of a derivative but I don't know if they are differentiable